# How to place a widget to bottom of page while using listview?

Tags: flutter

I must use a listview widget to display my widgets. At the bottom of the page there should be a button. Even there is not enough element in the listview the button should be placed to bottom.

I can achieve it by using column and expanded widget but it does not fulfil my needs. I must use a listview. How can I achieve it?

Comment: you want to add widget at end of listview or at the bottom of page. please add some code what you try and also try to add any image if possible. what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

in your list view builder, instead of using 'return' only, use:

```
if (index != yourlist.length -1) {
  // Not the last list item, so
  // return list item as usual, i.e. your original return statement
} else {
  // Last List Item, so
  // return a column that:
  // First children: last list item
  // Second children: your other widget that you want to put at the bottom
}
```